# How to draw the UML diagram which representing invocations between methods in the same class inheritance tree?

Tags: uml

I have the following classes A and B, and `entry()` is the entry point:

```java
abstract class A {
    abstract void a1();
    void a2() {
        ....
        a1();
    }
}
```

```java
class B extends A {
    void a1() {
      // overriden
    }
    void entry() {
      a2();
    }
}
```

I know how to draw the class diagram and sequence diagram for these two classes. But how should use a diagram to show the inheritance relationship and the invocation chain for them?